# Dynamic slideshow: what to choose?

Tags: php, jquery, jsp, symfony, slideshow

I'm programming a webpage with Symfony2 and I want to do something very specific at this point. I need a slideshow that:

- Pauses the presentation of images with a moseover.
- Dynamically includes all the pictures of a certain table in a MySQL database.
- Resizes all those images to fit inside the frame of the slideshow (without changing the ratio of the picture, remaining 1:1 and not deforming the picture).
- If possible, that those pictures are preloaded to avoid slow functioning.

For this task, I've been looking for already written jQuery slideshows (there are very nice slideshows out there). Now:

=> To dynamically include the images from the database, I would use JSP and write something simple (e.g. loop).

=> To resize the image my request is to make the image weight less. For example, the original image is 1,2 MB in size and 1000 x 1000 px in resolution size. Imagine to load 10 images like that in the slideshow. So what I look for is something that reduces all the aspects of the image (reduction in pixel size and paired compression of the file). For this, I thought of a server-side solution instead of a client-side one, for example some already written PHP script to resize images. (But how to make all those images get reduced?)

My question, finally, is to gather information from you, guys, regarding what you think about this issue: what I should use, how I should use it... I mean, I never came across this slideshow thing with these particular specifications, so I need some expert opinions to orient me.

All ideas are welcome.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: this is not the type of questions that fits the Q/A format on the StackExchange site's. It much to broaden and solicits debat and discussion. Please find a forum, which is the perfect place to ask these questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might look at http://galleria.io/, this is veeeeery elastic slideshow, with powerfull theming ability and bunch of [configurable options](http://galleria.io/docs/options/#list-of-options). It has few ways to [declare image data](http://galleria.io/docs/references/data/) too, so you can write your loop. When you set dimensions it automatically fits images to viewport (crop or not, as you set). Yes, it can [preload images](http://galleria.io/docs/options/preload/). Pause on hover you can achieve with [extend method](http://galleria.io/docs/options/extend/) or directly [in your theme](http://galleria.io/docs/themes/creating_a_theme/), if you would like to.

I think you will not find any jQuery slideshow which automatically resize images (I mean resize = physically change resolution). Sometimes they include script to prepare thumbnails, but there always is manual work.

I have used it [here](http://heartart.pl) for first time and I am pleased with it.